# Django project problem related to login and profile page

Tags: python, django

I am working on a python Django project. I have a little problem, When I make login through login form after registration. the main page was redirected to login page again despite configuring it to be redirected to profile page. I have searched and tried many solutions and the problem is still existed. Can anyone have an effective solution?

Github repo link : https://github.com/khaledomar77/vacc/tree/main

Comment: Did you manage to login?

Answer (score 0):

I see in your repository that you redirect with the following code:

```
if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('profile')
```

Have you tried printing 'user' to ensure that it isn't showing as none? I would venture to guess that this is your problem, as it isn't likely that the 'redirect' funtion itself from Django is failing.

The simplest solution would be to use django-allauth, which takes care of all the tricky authentication stuff for you.